# Error: \usepackage{tikz}

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am using Win8.1 with TeXLive installed and TeXWorks as IDE.
I want to make figures with Tikz but i always get said, that there is no package `tikz` when I try `\usepackage{tikz}`.

When I look into my TeXlive Manager I see that `pgf` is installed.

Anybody knows why I can't use TikZ with these settings?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user's own settings and distribution and cannot be reproduced in a generic setting.